# Exercise 2.2 on measuriability criterion from Probability for Statisticians

Tags: measure-theory

> Let $\mathcal{C}$ denote a $\bar{\pi}$ -system of subsets of $\Omega .$ Let $\mathcal{V}$ denote a vector space of functions; that is, $X+Y \in \mathcal{V}$ and $\alpha X \in \mathcal{V}$ for all $X, Y \in \mathcal{V}$ and all $\alpha \in R$ and, all the usual elementary facts hold.
>
> 1. Suppose that:
>    $ 1_{C} \in \mathcal{V} $ for all $C \in \mathcal{C}$. If $A_{n} \nearrow A$ with $1_{A_{n}} \in \mathcal{V},  $ then $1_{A} \in \mathcal{V}$
>    Show that $1_{A} \in \mathcal{V}$ for every $A \in \sigma[\mathcal{C}]$.
> 2. It then follows trivially that every simple function
>    $X_{n} \equiv \sum_{1}^{m} \alpha_{i} 1_{A_{i}}  $ is in $\mathcal{V}$
>    here $m \geq 1,$ all $\alpha_{i} \in R,$ and $\sum_{1}^{m} A_{i}=\Omega$ with all $A_{i} \in \sigma[\mathcal{C}]$
> 3. Now suppose further that $X_{n} \nearrow X$ for $X_{n}$ 's as in 2. implies that $X \in \mathcal{V} .$ Show that $\mathcal{V}$ contains all $\sigma[\mathcal{C}]$ -measurable functions.

Our teacher gives a hint of the first part of the question, asking us to show $\Lambda=\{A\in\sigma[\mathcal{C}]:1_A\in \mathcal{V}\}$ is a $\lambda$-system. In order to show $\Lambda$ is a $\lambda$-system, we need to show

- Show $\emptyset,\Omega\in\Lambda$

Since $C\in\mathcal{C} \Rightarrow 1_C\in\mathcal{V}.$ $ \Omega\in\mathcal{C}$, therefore $1_\Omega\in\mathcal{V}$. Also, $\Omega\in\sigma[\mathcal{C}]$, therefore $\Omega\in\Lambda$.

$1_\Omega+(-1_\Omega)\in \mathcal{V\Rightarrow1_{\emptyset}}\in \mathcal{V}$. Also $\emptyset\in \sigma[\mathcal{C}]$, therefore $\emptyset\in\Lambda.$

- Show if $A,B\in\Lambda,A\subset B,$then$B\backslash A\in\Lambda$

$A,B\in\Lambda\Rightarrow1_A,1_B\in\mathcal{V}$, therefore $-1_A\in \mathcal{V}$ so is $1_B-1_A\in \mathcal{V}$, therefore $1_{B\backslash A}\in \mathcal{V}$, so we have $B\backslash A\in\Lambda$

- Show if $A_{n} \in \Lambda \nearrow $ , $\cup^\infty_1 A_n\in \Lambda$.

Let $A_1,A_2...\in \Lambda \nearrow$, $1_{A_1},1_{A_2},...\in \mathcal{V}$. $\cup^\infty_1 A_n=\lim A_n=A \in \sigma(\mathcal{C})$ such that $1_A\in \mathcal{V}$, therefore $A\in\Lambda$.

We have proved that $\Lambda$ is a $\lambda$-system which by construction contains $\mathcal{C}$. Therefore $\Lambda\supset \lambda(\mathcal{C})=\sigma(\mathcal{C})$. By construction we also have that $\Lambda\subset\sigma(C)$, therefore $\Lambda=\sigma(\mathcal{C})$. Therefore every member  $A\in\Lambda=\sigma(\mathcal{C})$, we have that $1_A\in \mathcal{V}$.

**For part 2,** since we have proved $A\in\sigma(\mathcal{C})\Rightarrow 1_A\in \mathcal{V}$, following the property of a vector space, $X\in \mathcal{V}$.

**For part 3,**  Suppose that $X\geq 0$ and is $\sigma[\mathcal{C}]-measurable,$ then we know there exists $X_n\nearrow X, X_n$ are simple $\sigma[\mathcal{C}]$-measurable function and is in $\mathcal{V}$. So will the general function $X=X^+-X^-$, $X\in\mathcal{V}$ because $X^-,X^+\in \mathcal{V}$.

---

I am not sure if my proof is correct, especially for part 3. I am actually not sure what the question mean, before this excercise, we have :

> **Proposition 2.5 (The form of an $\mathcal{F}(\mathbf{Z})$ -measurable function)** Suppose that $Z$ is a measurable function on $(\Omega, \mathcal{A})$ and that $Y$ is $\mathcal{F}(Z)$ -measurable. Then there must exist a measurable function $g$ on $(\bar{R}, \overline{\mathcal{B}})$ such that $Y=g(Z)$.

**Proof.** nonnegative functions, general functions. This approach will be used again and again. Learn it!) Suppose that $Y=1_{D}$ for some set $D \in \mathcal{F}(Z),$ so that $Y$ is an indicator function that is $\mathcal{F}(Z)$ -measurable. Then we can rewrite $Y$ as $Y=1_{D}=1_{Z^{-1}(B)}=1_{B}(Z) \equiv g(Z),$ for some $B \in \overline{\mathcal{B}}$ that depends on $D,$ where $g(r) \equiv 1_{B}(r) .$ Thus the proposition holds for indicator functions. It holds for simple functions, since when all $B_{i} \in \overline{\mathcal{B}}$,
$$
Y=\sum_{1}^{m} c_{i} 1_{D_{i}}=\sum_{1}^{m} c_{i} 1_{Z^{-1}\left(B_{i}\right)}=\sum_{1}^{m} c_{i} 1_{B_{i}}(Z) \equiv g(Z)
$$
Let $Y \geq 0$ be $\mathcal{F}(Z)$ -measurable. Then there do exist $\nearrow$ simple $\mathcal{F}(Z)$ -measurable functions $Y_{n}$ such that $Y \equiv \lim _{n} Y_{n}=\lim _{n} g_{n}(Z)$ for the $\nearrow$ simple $\overline{\mathcal{B}}$ -measurable functions $g_{n} .$ Now let $g=\lim g_{n},$ which is $\bar{B}$ -measurable, and note that $Y=g(Z) .$ For general $Y=Y^{+}-Y^{-},$ use $g=g^{+}-g^{-}$.

---

My understanding is that: through part 1 and part 2 we have shown that if $X\in \mathcal{V}$ we can write it in a simple function form as some sorts of linear combination of the indicator function $1_A$, $A\in\sigma(\mathcal{C})$, which is why it is called $\sigma(\mathcal{C})$- measurable. In the given example, we need to have $Y\geq 0$ being measuable, then there exits $\lim Y_n=Y,$ $Y_n$ is increasing and $\mathcal{F}(X)$. In the question we are not given whether $X$ is positive or not, so I separate it into two part, with each being positive, therefore we can find $\lim X_n$. But I am actually not quite sure what I am doing here. Could some one please tell me what exact this question is trying to illustrate?

Comment: Is a $\overline{\pi}$-system different from a $\pi$-system?

Comment: @Jakobian yes, $\pi$-system doesn’t guarantee $\Omega$ in it

Comment: I never saw this kind of notation. But there is a lot of situations where we need to add $\Omega$ to a $\pi$-system so I see where it's coming from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> $A_{n} \in \Lambda \nearrow $

This line is an abuse of notation, I wasn't sure what you mean by this until I looked in your code. This could be replaced with $A_n\nearrow$, $A_n\in \Lambda$ to avoid misunderstandings.

> Let $A_1,A_2...\in \Lambda \nearrow$, $1_{A_1},1_{A_2},...\in \mathcal{V}$.

Here, there is no indication whatsoever that what you wrote after the comma is an actual conclusion from the previous. You could add something here to make that indication.

> $\cup^\infty_1 A_n=\lim A_n=A \in \sigma(\mathcal{C})$ such that $1_A\in \mathcal{V}$, therefore $A\in\Lambda$.

From the first line you bombard the reader by a formula that doesn't have an apparent revelance to the whole. You could first mention what you are trying to achieve here. Moreover, after that you reach $1_A\in \mathcal{V}$, but this is what you are trying to show. You should write how did you achieve at $1_A\in\mathcal{V}$. Hint: Use the continuity of measures.

> since we have proved $A\in\sigma(\mathcal{C})\Rightarrow 1_A\in \mathcal{V}$, following the property of a vector space, $X\in \mathcal{V}$.

This is a simplification I would be willing to take if you wrote something like "Let $X$ be a simple $\sigma[\mathcal{C}]$-measurable function". How it's written it's missing this assumption.

> Suppose that $X\geq 0$ and is $\sigma[\mathcal{C}]-measurable,$ then we know there exists $X_n\nearrow X, X_n$ are simple $\sigma[\mathcal{C}]$-measurable function and is in $\mathcal{V}$. So will the general function $X=X^+-X^-$, $X\in\mathcal{V}$ because $X^-,X^+\in \mathcal{V}$.

You didn't even write yet the conclusion that for non-negative $\sigma[\mathcal{C}]$-measurable functions we have that $X\in \mathcal{V}$, yet you've already jumped to the general case. You should have written that conclusion before talking about the general case.

Those are all my hints on how you could've written it better.

This is just illustrating how the "general machine" of proving things works in measure theory.

You prove something for indicator functions, simple functions, non-negative, and finally all measurable.

This theorem is important in itself for measure and/or probability theoretic proofs, and it's good to have it in mind.

Comment: sorry, by part c I meant part 3, I have corrected that. For $\Lambda$ is closed under monotone limits, I just picked up a sequence of sets that is increasing and has limit $A$ by definition of the $\sigma$-field, it must also be in $\sigma(\mathcal{C})$, and by the second condition given in part 1 , $1_A\in \mathcal{V}$. What I am trying to do is to simply show $A$ is both in $\sigma(\mathcal{C})$ and $1_A\in \mathcal{V}$, I am wondering how can I improve the proof to make it better? For the second suggestion I am not quite sure if I get it, back thanks for leading me to the "standard machine"

Comment: Hi, I understood I did part 3 completely wrong and rewrote my proof. But I am not very sure how to show $X\in\mathcal{V}$ as the question has outlined? I just take it as a given condition.